# Debian bridge doesn't accept IPv6 config

Tags: debian, networking, ipv6, bridge

I'm currently trying to configure my bridge in Debian 7.
I do have a working `config` for IPv4:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address xx.xx.xx.131
  netmask 255.255.255.192
  gateway xx.xx.xx.129
  bridge_ports eth0
  bridge_stp off
  bridge_fd 1
  bridge_hello 2
  bridge_maxage 12

iface br0 inet6 static
  address xx:xx:xx::2
  netmask 64
  gateway xxxx::1
```

But on boot my interface only comes up with a IPv4 address.
I also tried adding

```
up ip -6 addr add xx:xx:xx:2/64 dev br0
up ip -6 route add default via xxxx:1 dev br0
```

to the IPv4 config.
No success either. 
If I execute the `ip -6` commands listed above after the reboot IPv6 works just fine.

Caveat: I'm running a clean minimal install of Debian 7 nothing has yet been added.

Comment: Is IPv6 disabled on the bridge? Please post the result of `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/br0/disable_ipv6`.

Comment: hey jofel, the output is `0`

Comment: ok, then this is not the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any errors on journal?

I experienced same issue and found error like this:

```
# journalctl -u networking
YYYYMMDD  networking[416]: /etc/network/if-up.d/vzifup-post: 5: exec: /usr/sbin/vzifup-post: not found
YYYYMMDD  networking[416]: run-parts: /etc/network/if-up.d/vzifup-post exited with return code 127
YYYYMMDD  networking[416]: Failed to bring up eth0.
```

In my case, `apt purge vzctl` and worked fine.